# Installing OpenNebula on CentOS 6.5

Tags: shell, paas, opennebula

I am installing OpenNebula on my CentOS 6.9 server, which I have running inside a VirtualBox Machine.

While going through the installation process, I got stuck at this point:

```
# cat << EOT > /etc/yum.repos.d/opennebula.repo
```

This command does not respond at all: it simply goes to the next line and displays this: `>`

I am almost ready to finalise my installation, and this obstacle is a pain.

Suggestions, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I make the subject that you compile OpenNebula.
I know it may sound crazy, but it tends to give you better results in the future; starting in that you will not have all the OpenNebula files scattered throughout the system, but in a single directory.

Comment: With OP asking for help with cat<EOF> , you're suggesting OP rebuilds the project from scratch?

Isn't that exactly like someone asking about why the sky is blue, and you suggest they build a solar system?

Answer (score 0):

```
cat << EOT > /etc/yum.repos.d/opennebula.repo
>
```

This means that the shell session is waiting for more input.

<

So that's where you are.  The instructions you're following probably have a text block immediately following, terminated by EOT on a new-line.  Your input there will look like

```
cat << EOT > /etc/yum.repos.d/opennebula.repo
> this   <-- this is you typing
> that   <- or pasting stuff
> more   <- here too
> EOT    <- and finally here.
```

And you'll get the regular prompt back.